# How to iterate through list<int> property within ListView in Xamarin?

Tags: list, listview, xamarin, converters

I'm trying to use my int to image converter by iterating through list proptery in my listview.
The problem is, i don't know how to do proper binding so XAML knows, that it should bind to nested list item instead of top object.

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="4" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Allergens}" 
              x:Name="AllergensViewModel"
              IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Allergen">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout CompressedLayout.IsHeadless="true">
                            <Frame Grid.ColumnSpan="4" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="#151515" HeightRequest="28" CornerRadius="5" Margin="0,2" Padding="6">
                                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Types}">
                                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="20" TextColor="White" LineBreakMode="NoWrap"/>
                                                **Here**-----> <ffimageloading:CachedImage Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" DownsampleToViewSize="true" Source="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource AllergenConverter},  Mode=OneWay}"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListView>
                            </Frame>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

How can i use Listview withing listview, so that XAML knows which binding i am referencing?

Comment: it is generally a bad idea to nest ListViews.  However, the content of the inner ListView template will be the current element of `Types`, whatever that is

Comment: It is list<int> - but i cannot access individual items, as {Binding .} still references parent object. But if nesting ListView is a bad idea, what else could I do?

Comment: `"{Binding .}"` should refer to the current `int` in `Types`.  If it doesn't something is going wrong in your model.  If `Types` is just a `List<int>` then why are you binding to `Name` in the `Label`?

Comment: Tried other approach and it is a leftover. Things is, this Binding still applies to 'model:Allergen', and not to ItemsSource defined in inner listView :<

Comment: have you tried removing `x:DataType`?

Comment: It did help, and xaml seems to be seeing '{Binding .}' as int32. But converter still receives null, even though property is defined

Comment: since you haven't posted the code for the converter it's difficult to comment on that

Answer (score 0):

Binding always refer to the current `object` ,you need to make it clear.

If your Viewmodel looks like

```
public class HomeViewModel : BaseModel
{
   public List<Allergen> Allergens { get; set; }
}

public class Allergen
{
    public List<int> Types { get; set; }
}
```

And the binding relationship like below

```
|    View             |    Property       |
|---------------------|-------------------|
|    Page             |    HomeViewModel  |
|    Outer ListView   |    Allergens      |
|    Outer ViewCell   |    Allergen       |
|    Inner ListView   |    Types          |
|    Image            |    int            |
```

In this way ， the vaule you get from `Convert` method in `Converter` is `int` value in `Types`.

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    //here value is a `int`
}
```